# What happens when the below code executed?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am not getting why the below is executing but not when tried in other form:

```
struct ListNode* &ptr2  = ptr;  //This is executing
struct ListNode* ptr2; // This is not executing
&ptr2  = ptr;
```

Can anyone explain about the code, How it works?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `rcpp` so i will edit out the tag.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of code, `struct ListNode* &ptr2 = ptr;` , a reference to a pointer variable ptr is created and assigned to another pointer variable ptr2. This means that ptr2 is simply an alias for ptr and any changes made to ptr2 will also affect ptr.

In the second line of code, `struct ListNode* ptr2;` , a pointer variable ptr2 is declared but not initialized. This means that ptr2 does not currently point to any memory location.

In the third line of code, `&ptr2 = ptr;` , you are attempting to assign the address of ptr to ptr2. However, ptr2 is not a reference to a pointer variable, so this line of code will not compile.

Comment: I would emphasize the difference of `=` in _initialization_ of 1st line versus the `=` in _assignment expression_ in the 3rd line. IMHO, OP is confused by this, and maybe by the fact as well that a `&` means a _reference_ in a _declaration_ vs. the _address-of operator_ in an _expression_. (I mean, I don't like to read "assign" in your first sentence.) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first, the type of `ptr2` is `struct ListNode* &` – a reference to a pointer – and it is initialized as a reference to `ptr`.
The names "ptr" and "ptr2" refer to the same object.

It is the same situation as

```
int x = 0;
int& y = x;
```

In the second, the type of `ptr2` is `struct ListNode*` and you then attempt to assign the *value* of `ptr` to the *address* of `ptr2`, which is impossible.
This is the same situation as

```
int x = 0;
int* y;
&y = x;
```